# Can not install vue-cli, no matching version found

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli

I can not install vue-cli, it asks me to install specific express-serve-static package, however i could not install that package as well. How can i solve this issue?

When I am trying to install vue-cli,

```sh
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

gives me the error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @types/express-serve-static-core@4.17.13.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'apollo-server-express'
```

- Then I just tried to install express-serve-static

```sh
$ npm install -g @types/express-serve-static-core
+ @types/express-serve-static-core@4.17.12
updated 1 package in 4.536s
```

- As you can see, npm did not install the 4.17.13, then i just change the command:

```sh
$ npm install -g @types/express-serve-static-core@4.17.13
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @types/express-serve-static-core@4.17.13.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Node and npm version:

```sh
$ node -v
v14.15.1

$ which node
.../Desktop/node_and_npm/node-v14.15.1-darwin-x64/bin/node

$ npm -v
6.14.8

$ which npm
.../Desktop/node_and_npm/node-v14.15.1-darwin-x64/bin/npm
```

Comment: try `npm update -g @vue/cli` only, remove the sudo